# nodejs understaning the functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have start to work with Nodejs and I have "Basic" understandable question

is there any whay to know what I can get out of a function ?

for example :

I'm using this package to scan bluetooth
[node-bluetooth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bluetooth#connect)

I undesrand the II have create a device , then I "wait" it to replay

so I'm waiting for

```
on.finish

or 

on.found
```

how can I know if there are more "function\answers" to the function?

*** I took this function as an example , could be any other function

I just want it to scan in a loop and show me the devcies around him
every 1 min of scanning (I know the scan took around 12 seconds)

Thanks ,

Comment: why cant you just read the docs and their official github page

Comment: there is nothing on the page https://github.com/song940/node-bluetooth#readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bluetooth#connect) and/or reading the [code](https://github.com/song940/node-bluetooth#readme) are your two choices for this module.

There are no Javascript language features that would tell you what this module of code is supposed to do or what features it has.

Comment: OK , I thought maybe there is a "list" \ "Help" that can show it to me ....  so if I look at the example - I can only use the commands in the examples?

Comment: @Afik_Android - Or, look at the code and see if there's anything else in the code that isn't in the documentation.